# Sketch Filter for Images for a react native app

Tags: react-native, image, image-processing, react-native-image

I am creating a react native app, it is like a trace-and-sketch kind of app, so one of its key features is an image background removal which basically clears out any colour from the image and enhances its edges, kind of like the sketch filter on instagram[here's an image which shows the effect of the sketch filter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mlu3I.png)

I've used "react-native-image-filter-kit": "^0.7.1" and react-native-photo-editor
but I cant achieve the desired result.

Is there any library or any paid SDK which will help me achieve this.
Thanks!

I've used "react-native-image-filter-kit": "^0.7.1" and react-native-photo-editor
but I cant achieve the desired result.

using the Saturate, ColorTone and greyscale from react-native-image-filter-kit[before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xpvWy.jpg), I got to some point but still couldn't achieve what I was looking for
[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sndnd.png)

Comment: If you are willing to get into creating shaders, I think with react native skia you could do that